# Email attachment sent using SKPSMTPMessage appears in iOS mail client as contact

Tags: ios, email, smtp

I have tested the code for sending attachments using this useful library:

[Skpsmtpmessage library](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)

The email seems to get sent correctly, and when I view it through hotmail or gmail clients I see the jpeg image. However, when I view this same email through an iOS mail client, the attachment appears as a "contact" and clicking on this gives me the option to save the file as a new contact.

I have tried sending an email with jpeg attachment from hotmail, and when I do this it appears correctly in the iOS client.

Does anyone know whether this is the code or iOS getting it wrong?

```
//the guts of the message.
SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
testMsg.fromEmail = @"aname@gmail.com";
testMsg.toEmail = @"aname@gmail.com";
testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"aname@gmail.com";
testMsg.pass = @"password";
testMsg.subject = @"The message subject";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!

// Only do this for self-signed certs!
// testMsg.validateSSLChain = NO;
testMsg.delegate = self;

//email contents
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSString * bodyMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The message body"];

// email image if it exists

NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/file.jpeg"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSMutableArray* parts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// add plain part
NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           bodyMessage ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

[parts addObject: plainPart];


// add attachments
NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jpgPath]; 

NSString *directory = @"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"file.jpeg\"";
NSString *attachment = @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"file.jpeg\"";

NSDictionary *image_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                directory,kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                attachment,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
                                [attachmentData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                                @"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

[parts addObject: image_part];
testMsg.parts = parts;
[testMsg send];
```

Comment: Did this work? I'm trying to add an jpeg image to an email. Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I was trying to send an email in a background thread which ended up being a no no in the end anyway. I resorted to using a proxying server to relay the the message.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
 NSString *directory = @"text/directory;...
```

to

```
 NSString *directory = @"text/jpeg;...
```

I hope this works for you!

Steffen